# Insert a variable number of rows

Tags: loops, macros, sas, datastep

Currently, my macro is running to insert a constant number of rows:

```
%MACRO ADD_PERIOD;

%DO P = 1 %TO 39;
```

Would I be able to modify this macro or create a new macro to run this, not 39 times, but replace the number of loops with a variable I have from another table?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `call symput` to turn that variable(my_var) into a `macro` variable(loop_var)

```
data _null_;
set your_table;
call symput("loop_var", my_var);
run;
```

and use `&` to resolve the macro variable into your code

```
%MACRO ADD_PERIOD;

%DO P = 1 %TO &loop_var;
```

You could also pass that macro variable as parameters into your macro.

```
 %MACRO ADD_PERIOD(loop_var);
```